# Swift custom URL scheme adopting dark mode

Tags: swift, wkwebview, macos-catalina

I have an app which supplies some content via its custom URL handler using WkWebView, and find its content does not automatically adopt appearance - dark/light changes.

However, if I launch a web inspector, its toggle widget **does** affect my view's content, so I'm thinking my trivial addition is not sufficient?

Here's what I added to my 'start' task handler:

```
    //  Dovetail with dark mode handling style sheet
    let asset = NSString.string(fromAsset: "dark-css")
    let script = WKUserScript.init(source: asset, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

where dark-css is simply:

```
:root {
    color-scheme: light dark;
}
```

In-lining this css snippet into the html does not favor better, and I'm leaning towards the handler approach vs editing many files, and hoping if I select amenable colors within the html sources, things should "just work" when I toggle the appearance in the Settings app?